# Using NAS as ESXi Datastore?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Is there a way to add an external USB HDD that is connected to my Netgear Rangemax router via USB to ESXi 4.0 as a datastore? The external is formatted as NTFS and I have data on it already.

Comment: does the rangemax support nfs?

Answer (score 8):

Can the NAS expose the drive via either iSCSI or NFS? If so, yes. Be prepared for *awful* performance, though. You'll be using a desktop-class hard drive, connected via USB to an underpowered router that isn't intended to ship around the amounts of data you'll be throwing at it.

Comment: NTFS and "existing data" will also be a problem, but as Erik said, the main problem is going to be... everything else.

Comment: Agreed! I guess it's fair enough if you're just having a play but don't even contemplate it in production!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this!

Successfully or not, that is the question..

We connected a Buffalo TeraStation over USB to one of the ESX hosts, then connected the device to a Fedora Linux VM, and served up the (pre-existing NTFS contents) as a NAS datastore.

We used it only for VM backups and archives, since the performance was *ABYSMAL*.

I don't remember exact performance numbers, but it was around 20x slower than the local RAID5  disks in the host, and maybe 100x slower than the FibreChannel SAN.

(I'm vaguely remembering 3MB/sec vs 60MB/sec vs 300MB/sec??)

But it was *incredibly* useful as a place to stash temporary backups off the SAN during any kind of risky maintenance, and also to transfer VMs between the data center and the office.

(A 2TB disk in a taxi can provide better throughput than a 100Mbit WAN!)

Comment: Obligatory A.S. Tanenbaum quote (the second one from the top): http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum.

Comment: I remember seeing somebody once calculate the bandwidth of a 747 cargo container filled with DVDs...

Comment: 2TB hard disks are the way to go.